# VBA Lopping through a Union with non-contiguous ranges

Tags: vba

I'm creating a report where I'm looking at a date column, and based on the value in that column (falling between a range), I increment an aggregate with the value in the previous cell. Because the dates are in non-contiguous columns, I'm using a Union range. I've hard coded the cell values below and deleted the rest of the code to hone in on the looping issue. My loop goes through 5 times, but each time the values $I$2 and the same date value appears. How can I get my loop to go to cell K2 and beyond?

```
Dim c as Range

Range("I2").Select
Set installmentRng = Union(Cells(2, 9), Cells(2, 11), Cells(2, 13), Cells(2, 15), Cells(2, 17))

For Each c In installmentRng
    MsgBox (ActiveCell.Value)
    MsgBox (ActiveCell.Address)
Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the `ActiveCell.Value` with `c.Value`, I think your problem is solved.

You shouldn't use `Select` at all, if possible. Also, if you replace `Msgbox` with `Debug.Print`, your troubleshooting will be a lot less painful. Press Ctrl+G to see the output.

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveCell` is the cell where the focus is on (with other words, if the user starts to type something, it will go into this cell).
While working on worksheet data in VBA, you usually don't need to deal with the `ActiveCell`. In your case, the loop is not changing the `ActiveCell` (and there is no need to do so ). Instead, the `Range`-Variable `c` will change, and you can work with that:

```
For Each c In installmentRng
    MsgBox c.Value
    MsgBox c.Address
Next c
```

Two additionally remarks:
**(1)** no need for the `Range("I2").Select` - statement. This changes the `ActiveCell` - but as said, this is not necessary (you need the `Select`-statement nearly never, but it's often seen in (bad) VBA-code because the macro-recorder uses it.
**(2)** Do not put parenthesises around the msgBox parameter.

Comment: Thank you!! Works!